# How to add map using package flutter_map?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mapbox, fluttermap

I`m using package [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) to add map in my app (I do step by step in [this video](https://youtu.be/YuwhlhaM1eM?si=bxDAFuYgKSQ3xtgQ)). My code like this:

```
FlutterMap(
  mapController: mapController,
  options: MapOptions(
    initialCenter: const LatLng(51.5, -0.09),
    initialZoom: 5,
  ),
  children: [
    TileLayer(
      tileProvider: AssetTileProvider(),
      urlTemplate:
          'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    ),
  ],
),
```

But when i run, it show error in console:

```
Unable to load asset: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/5/15/10.png"
Unable to load asset: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/5/20/10.png"
...
```

And then i do step by step again in other video: https://youtu.be/hZwrcOTxDJI?si=2XiBv7_iKbZtFaDR
It still show error: `Unable to load asset: ...`
I don't know why it's causing this issue even though I followed the instructions correctly. Can someone help me, please? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using tileProvider as an AssetProvider.

You should be using [NetworkTileProvider](https://docs.fleaflet.dev/layers/tile-layer/tile-providers).